# "Consist in" vs. "consist of"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences, prepositions

I would like to clarify this once and for all: What is the correct use of "consist in" vs. "consist of"?

> "Meditation consists in/of attentive watchfulness."
>
> "The body consists in/of cells."

More examples of correct and incorrect uses would be appreciated.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/193852/50720 may help.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

*Of* is the correct preposition to use in your second example:

> The body consists of cells.

*In* is the correct preposition to use in your first example:

> Meditation consists in attentive watchfulness.

*Consist of* means to be composed or made up of, while *[consist in](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consist_in)*
means:

> To have the thing mentioned as the only or most important part.
>   *Tolerance consists in respecting other people’s opinions.*

Comment: How about listing the underlying ideas of a mechanism? Like, "IP networking consists [in/of] routing strategies and addressing principles"

Answer (score 29):

I think both the above answers are correct, but missing a key point that 'consist of' is normally used with more tangible objects whereas 'consist in' has an esoteric quality to it.  There's a good explanation here about [the difference](http://languagetips.wordpress.com/2009/10/01/language-tips-consists-of-or-consists-in-provedproven-again/):

> American writers often ignore this distinction. Consist of is used in reference to materials; it precedes the physical elements that compose a tangible thing. The well-worn example is that concrete consists of sand, gravel, cement, and water.
>
> Consist in (= to have as its essence) refers to abstract elements or qualities or Intangible things. Thus, a good moral character consists in integrity, decency, fairness, and compassion.  ...
>
> This construction is literary in tone and is not often seen today in general writing. Sad to say, it may now seem creaky to most readers.

(Bryan Garner, *Modern American Usage* (3rd ed 2009), quoted in *Language Usage Weblog* October 1, 2009)

I have to agree about the 'creaky' bit.  I didn't even know it was legitimate to say "consist in" until I saw this question, and the examples in the earlier answers sound really strange to my ears.

Answer (score 11):

*Consist of X* means *made up of X*, while *consist in X* means *have X as essential feature*. The meaning is slightly different. For example,

> His breakfast **consists of** noodles, eggs and bananas.
>
> Her music **consists in** inspiring others.

One would write

> Meditation **consists in** attentive watchfulness

to mean that watchfulness is an essential feature of meditation and

> The body **consists of** cells

to mean that cells make up the body.

Answer (score -1):

This is a belated observation, but the article was referred to in a recent **Greatest hits from previous weeks** newsletter, and I think this contribution might be worthwhile.

I've come across this distinction before but had forgotten it. On reading the article, one of the contributors says **The well-worn example is that concrete consists of sand, gravel, cement, and water.** This was the point for then giving an example of using the other form with concrete. Since the contrast wasn't made then I'll offer my own: **Concreteness (the nature of concrete) consists in strength, durability, and mouldability.**

Answer (score -1):

- **Consist of** is related to material things.
- **E.g.,** The body consists of cells.
- **consist in** is related to non-material things.
- **E.g.,** Meditation consists in attentive watchfulness.