# What is the correct use of foundation in / foundation of?

Tags: prepositions

A while back, the question was asked (and answered): [*Correct use of consist in / consist of*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61600/consist-in-vs-consist-of).

I have a similar question:

Which of the following is correct:

"The objective of these lessons is to provide a solid foundation ***in*** the correct usage of prepositions."

vs.

"The objective of these lessons is to provide a solid foundation ***of*** the correct usage of prepositions."

**EDIT**: Here is the full context where I'm looking to select the right preposition:

> "It is important that students understand the fundamental principles of manufacturing. The objective of the lessons is to provide a solid foundation **[in/of]** the science and techniques necessary for that understanding."

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61600/consist-in-vs-consist-of

Answer (score 2):

If I had to choose one or the other, I'd select *a solid foundation in*, but like Régis Roux I'd prefer *a solid foundation for*.  The lessons are providing a solid foundation **upon which** our further understanding of *the correct usage of prepositions* will rest.  So the foundation is **for** them.

Comment: Well, the actual sentence I was interested in was this:

Comment: It was part of the paragraph "It is important that students understand the fundamental principles of manufacturing. The objective of the lessons is to provide a solid foundation _**in/of**_ the science and techniques necessary for that understanding." So the "for" is already there in the context you indicated.

Comment: I'd write it this way:  .."The objective of the lessons is to provide a solid foundation **for** the science and techniques necessary for that understanding."  but the sentence is a bit of a mess.  It's not very clear if the foundation is for the science or the techniques, and which of them are necessary for "that understanding"  But I'd definitely use "for".

Comment: Now that we have "in," "of", and "for," I'm wondering how to keep track of the proper usage for each.

Comment: @user25076 ... The Prepositio Book by Tom Cole is excellent book for starting in understanding of this matter!

Comment: @RickO'Shey: Look up those three prepositions in a [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for), and you'll see well over a dozen meanings for two of them, and at least 10 for the third. There's no way to briefly sum up how those three words can be used – they are nearly interchangable in some contexts, and have several nuances in their own right. As a side note, please provide the sentence you want to use a word in **in your question**, not in a comment, to prevent "false starts". (You ought to do that when you ask, and, if you didn't, the question should be edited).

Answer (score 1):

Solid foundation of hours of daily training, in general fitness, for military service.

foundation of [components of the foundation]
foundation in [domain of the foundation]
foundation for [purpose of the foundation].