# How does 'consist' compound with 'in' mean “to have as an essential feature”?

Tags: etymology

> [1.1. [consist in]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/consist?q=consist+in#consist__9) = Have as an essential feature

How did the Latin *com-* + *sistere*  compound to mean 1.1 above? It may help to read ODO's own conjecture of the etymology (see the link above).

> [[Etymonline for **consist (v.)** :]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=consist&searchmode=none) 1520s, from Middle French *consister* (14c.) or directly from Latin *consistere* "to stand firm, take a standing position, stop, halt,"
>   from *com-* "together" (see [com-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=com-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + *sistere* "to place," causative of stare "to stand, be standing" (see [stay](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stay&allowed_in_frame=0) (v.)). Related: Consisted; consisting.

Answer (score 3):

The Latin word *consisto* already had this (additional) sense, according to [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dconsisto):

> 2. (According to I. B. 2.) *To be or remain firm, unshaken, immovable, steadfast, to be at rest, to stand one's ground, to continue, endure, subsist, be, exist* ...
>
> ...
>
> 4. In general, *to be, exist* ...
>
> 4 (b). With *in, ex*, or the simple ablative (in Quintilian also with *circa* and *inter*; vide infra), **to consist in** or **of, to depend upon**:
>
> “major pars victūs eorum in lacte, caseo, carne consistit,” Caes. B. G. 6, 22: “omnis per se natura duabus Constitit in rebus,” Lucr. 1, 420: “e quibus haec rerum summa consistat,” id. 1, 236; so with ex, id. 1, 839; 1, 873 al.; with abl.: “deveniunt in talis disposturas, Qualibus haec rerum consistit summa,” id. 1, 1028; 5, 61; 5, 66: “vita omnis in venationibus atque in studiis rei militaris consistit,” Caes. B. G. 6, 21: “in eo salus et vita optimi cujusque **consistit**,” Cic. Phil. 3, 8, 19: “in hoc summa judicii causaque tota consistit,” id. Quint. 9, 32; cf. id. de Or. 1, 40, 182: “causam belli in personā tuā,” id. Phil. 2, 22, 53: “in quibus vita beata,” id. Tusc. 5, 14, 40: “in unā honestate omne bonum,” id. ib. 5, 14, 42: “in nomine controversia,” Quint. 7, 3, 7; 8, 3, 57: “in actu rhetoricen,” id. 2, 18, 2; 6, 3, 42: “spes omnis consistebat Datami in se locique naturā,” Nep. Dat. 8, 3.—With abl., Quint. 12, 10, 59: “omnis quaestio circa res personasque consistere videtur,” id. 3, 5, 7; 6, 3, 19: “quaestio inter utile atque honestum consistet,” id. 3, 8, 24. —

So the word already had this meaning in classical Latin, which makes its post-classical history irrelevant. *Con-sisto* literally means "stand together in x" in Latin.

As to how it acquired this meaning in Latin, I do not know.

Adding the prefix *con-* "together" to the verb *sisto*, "to (cause to) stand", resulted in the meaning "to go and stand (somewhere), to stop, to stand still".

Lewis & Short (see above) suggest that it more or less went from "stand together, stand firm" to "be/exist" to "be in essence" to "be represented in essence in [a thing or quality]".

But *con-* also often indicates that the action represented by the simple (= without affixes) verb comes to a natural end, as can perhaps be seen in *conclude, convert, confer*. The end 'comes together' with the beginning of the action, as it were. *Sisto/sto* "stand" is often close in meaning to "be" and "exist", as can be observed in *existo* as well, which means "to stand out, to exist".

It is possible that *consisto* went from "stand together" to "stand complete" to "be complete" to "be in essence" to "be represented in essence in [a thing or quality]". But perhaps we would be wiser to follow Lewis & Short.

I don't think the exact semanto-etymological path is known.

Note that a somewhat similar path is also present in Germanic, as in Dutch:

> staan = to stand
>
> bestaan = to (continue to) exist
>
> bestaan uit = to consist of
>
> bestaan in = to consist in

Perhaps this originates in a loan translation from Latin. That is certainly possible for *bestaan uit* and *bestaan in*, but hardly for *bestaan* "exist", because that use already existed [in Old Dutch and Old High German](http://gtb.inl.nl/iWDB/search?actie=article&wdb=ONW&id=ID769).

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit: My point was that the word already had this meaning in classical Latin, which makes its post-classical history irrelevant. It literally means "stand together in x".

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry to bother you again, but can you please write more about how `stand together in x` evolved to mean `Have as an essential feature`? I'm confused because I'm guessing: 'Y stands together in X' = 'X has an essential feature, Y.'. So the order is reversed? Where did I err?

Comment: @LePressentiment: I don't think that is known, but I have added some speculation to my answer above. I don't follow your reasoning that *'Y stands together in X' = 'X has an essential feature, Y'*, though.

Comment: +1. Many thanks. Your conjecture and your analogy to Dutch really help, even if it cannot be proven!

Comment: About `don't follow your reasoning that 'Y stands together in X' = 'X has an essential feature, Y', though`: please see my changed OP. I try to explain this more clearly. Better?

Comment: @LePressentiment: I'm still not sure I understand. But I wouldn't pay too much attention the exact wording of a dictionary definition: it is usually less precise; it is rather meant to give you a general idea. The Oxford English Dictionary has a more detailed and pehaps better definition, with **to have its being in** as a basis: http://pastebin.com/vaq8AW84

Answer (score 0):

[consist](https://boercade.com/index.php?title=Consist)  = [con](https://boercade.com/index.php?title=Co-/con-/com-) + [sist](https://boercade.com/index.php?title=Sist)

> con-: together, with
>
> sist: derived from Latin "sistere", meaning "stand"

So **consist** means:

```
Stand together/with.
```

**Usage1：cosist of**

```
A is B of standing together.
```

=>

```
A is B of consisting.
```

as time goes on, it turns slowly into：

```
A consists of B.
```

So "***consist of***" turns into the meaning: "*to be formed from two or more things*".

**Usage2：consist in**

```
A stands with in (within) B.
```

So "***consist in***" means “*to exist in or depend on something*”.

For more details, you can visit page:
https://boercade.com/index.php?title=Consist