# What's the difference between “delay in” and “delay of”?

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference between “delay in” and “delay of”? I have seen many examples of both, but I can't guess the difference.

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: It's just a generic question.

Comment: I would understand if this question were flagged as a far too simple one, but I'm not able to see what is unclear about it. I believe it's almost identical to this one: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61600/consist-in-vs-consist-of which was granted with 14 points. It looks like I'm not able to understand the proper way of asking questions so, I will refrain from asking and will continue using this site to consult the excellent an useful information in the already asked ones. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Delay of"** seems to be a *time-based delay* ("Delay of five seconds"), whereas **"Delay in"** refers to *objects* that are delayed "A delay in the delivery of new mobile phones".

I think you cannot say "there was a delay in five seconds", or "There was a delay of the delivery of mobile phones".

Comment: Thanks a lot.  
A search in CORPUS OF GLOBAL WEB-BASED ENGLISH (GloWbE) rendered results that are consistent with your answer:  "delay of" collocated within 3 words with "seconds|minutes|hours|days|weeks|months|years" after it, rendered 243 hits. With "delay in" it rendered just 6 hits.   "delay of" collocated within 3 words with "delivery|arrival|payment|flight|service" after it, rendered 36 hits. With "delay in" it rendered 353 hits.

Comment: Nice to know! Also like your statistical approach towards figuring it out.